# Silverlight Memory Usage: Task Manager vs ANTS vs SciTech

Tags: silverlight, memory-leaks

Task Manager says that IE is using over 500MB of private working set.

Both ANTS Memory Profiler and SciTech .NET Memory profiler say I'm running between 50 and 75 MB.

How do I explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question as to what the difference is, but it is a great video around your first statement http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/MED07

Comment: Actually that did lead me to the answer. Using the VMMAP tool he recommended I was able to see the unmanaged memory that was being used. Of course that leads to other questions...